# docker container: curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1 port 4000: No route to host

Tags: linux, docker

I have `graphql` server running on the main machine on 4000 port

curl from the machine works well and I got what I expect:

`curl   -X POST   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   --data '{ "query": "{ me { _id } }" }'   http://localhost:4000/graphq`

when I do curl on container:

`curl http://172.17.0.1`

I got:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.16.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It shows me that I can reach `ngnix` from container and it indicates for me that I can reach my machine from the container.

but when I curl form container:

`curl   -X POST   -H "Content-Type: application/json"   --data '{ "query": "{ me { _id } }" }'   http://172.17.0.1:4000/graphql`

I got:

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.17.0.1 port 4000: No route to host`

Comment: you can try to reach using the container name instead of IP

Comment: graphql is running not on the container

Comment: Can you forward port 4000 into the container `docker run -p 4000:4000 ...` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to configure Nginx for public access because the docker uses a special network like it does have different network range you have to specify the network range in the Nginx server.

please refer the following link:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/

https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-nginx-access-control-howto/